# How to attach one of many sets of implementations to an object?

Tags: oop, inheritance, interface, abstract-class, composition

Suppose I'm modeling a collection of Agents.  These agents might be controlled by a Player or by a Bot.  Additionally, each Agent has a Role - such as Explorer or Engineer.  All Roles share the same common actions, but each one might implement the actions a little differently.  Ideally, you would be able to invoke agentInstance.move(), and the action would play out depending on what Role they have.

I've been wrestling with how to model this for a while, and looked through the [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and [Template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) patterns specifically - but I'm not sure they're what I need.

One idea is to make Player and Bot subclasses of abstract Agent, and to make Explorer and Engineer subclasses of abstract Role.  Then each Agent would have a Role.  However, that would seem to imply that I would have to pass-through my commands like this: `agentInstance.getRole().move()`, or create helper functions like `agentInstance.move(){ this.role.move(); }` - which seems a bit inelegant.

[image: Example Model - Note that Agent and Role would have to share methods by coincidence.]

I'm also aware that my designs can be a bit interface-deficient, so I considered modeling the Roles as interfaces and sub-interfaces with default implementations that are then inherited by Agent, but that feels like a solution looking for a problem.

So - what's the best way to go about modeling this?  What considerations are crucial to the decision, especially with how similar Java 8 interfaces and abstract classes are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

- I will make Role an interface since it has no attribute. Explorer and
  Engineer will be class not interface b'coz that is how Strategy
  works.
- Player and Bot will be associated with Agent so that they can issue
  orders to Agent.

For me, there are 2 crucial considerations when doing OOP Analysis and Design:

- Does it solve my problem? If it does then dont fix it! Future problems
  are for future.
- It has to be as easy to refactor as possible. As new requirements
  come in you will have to do a lot of refactoring.

[image]

Comment: That's fair - what are your thoughts on the need to "tunnel" commands via agent.role.move()?  Is that not actually as dirty as it seems to me?

Comment: It is acceptable for me since the whole point is to use Polymorphism. But it will be better if Player/Bot only has to call agentInstance.move(). And then you delegate the Move() behaviour to the Role of the agent (By calling Role.Move() inside Agent.Move() for example). Then depending on the Role you give to that Agent it will Move differently. But that mostly depends on the business your are modeling.